# Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int and Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean

Tags: php, mysqli

the code is for inserting user data in database 
getting error on

```
$run = mysqli_query($con,$check_email);
```

> Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int

and

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean

```
    <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","users_db");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo 'connection was not established'. mysqli_connect_error();
    }

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
             $user_name = $_POST['name'];
             $user_pass = $_POST['pass'];
             $user_email = $_POST['email'];

             if($user_name==''){
                 echo "<script>alert('please Enter your Nmae!')</script>";
                 exit();
             }
             if($user_pass==''){
                 echo "<script>alert('please Enter your password!')</script>";
                 exit();
             }
             if($user_email==''){
                 echo "<script>alert('please Enter your Email!')</script>";
                 exit();
             }

                 $check_email = "select * from users where user_email='$user_email'";

                $run = mysqli_query($con,$check_email);
                if(mysqli_num_rows($run>0)){
                    echo "<script>alert('Email $user_email is already exist in database please try another one')</script>";
                    exit();
                }
                $query = "insert into users(user_name,user_pass,user_email) values ('$user_name','$user_pass','$user_email')";
                if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){

                    echo "<script>alert('Registration completed')</script>";
                }
                else{
                    echo"<script>alert('Data not inserted')</script>";
                }

             }  
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax is wrong

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($run>0)){
```

this should be

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($run) > 0){
                          ^ should be moved
```

This should fix both the errors.

Comment: Its accepted my data and if email already existed then got the popup that email with this is already in database

Comment: no before that i had created html page with username password email and button onclick of button it inserted the data

Comment: can you share your email.?because i'm new in PHP development so i need lots of help for creating my TY level project..

Answer (score -1):

You have done small mistake in mysqli_num_rows.

change from :

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($run>0)){
```

to

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($run) > 0){
```

Comment: any difference from above answer??